# How to fix error Error: This fragment inner class should be static (com.example.UserSettingActivity.MyPreferenceFragment) [ValidFragment]

Tags: android, android-fragments, inner-classes

I am just about to release an apk, but when I try to create a signed apk an error appears:

```
Error: This fragment inner class should be static (com.example.UserSettingActivity.MyPreferenceFragment) [ValidFragment]
```

which does not appear when I build the app for my phone. What is going on?

Below is the code which causes the trouble:

```
public class UserSettingActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

    private Preference myPreference;
    MainActivity.MyCallBack callBack;

   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, new MyPreferenceFragment()).commit();
    }

    public class MyPreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragment { // OFFENDING LINE
        @Override
        public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);

            myPreference = findPreference("reset");
            myPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
                public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference arg0) {
                    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(UserSettingActivity.this);
                    alertDialog.setMessage(R.string.deleteDB);
                    alertDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    alertDialog.setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(UserSettingActivity.this);
                            db.open();
                            db.resetDatabase();
                            callBack = MainActivity.mCallback;
                            callBack.refreshMainActivity();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

}
```

I am not quite sure myself what this code does, and it did work all the time. Except I am trying to create a signed apk! How can I resolve this issue?

I can make this static, but then I run into problems later on when the static class uses the surrounding class...

Comment: Having `Fragment` as inner class causes the problem. Create a new java file for the `MyPreferenceFragment`

Comment: Ok I will try that. I don't like inner classes anyway, but that code was just some example code or something....

Comment: But I need to somehow pass the `MyPreferenceFragment` the context, which I cannot do through an constructor (different error shows up). So I have to do something like this?
`MyPreferenceFragment frag = new MyPreferenceFragment();
        frag.setContext(this);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, frag).commit();`
Looks a bit cumbersome....

Comment: Wherever you want context in fragment use getActivity() method. No need to set context

Comment: But then I have to change something in the manifest or in thousand other files. And probably the whole app won't work then, which will me cost weeks to figure out... I leave it as it it. But thanks for the hint